# Why is this For Loop overwriting the contents of my dictionary strangely?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, for-loop, object

I am trying to convert my pandas DataFrame data into a different medium which is easily represented via JSON. I have chosen to do this by turning it into python dictionaries then converting it into JSON.

The problem I am encountering is that the data I am putting through the process of formatting is coming out in a different order than expected - the values I am expecting are being replaced by the last values in my for loop.

Here is a reproducible example, which is split between 2 files:

```py
    import re
    import pandas as pd
    import json
    
    from help import Model  # Note! this is another file help.py
    
    jan = {'Month': ["January", "January", "January", "January"],
           'Date': ['1st', '2nd', '28th', '29th'],
           'a': ["j1a", "a3x", "d9c", "h9c"],
           'b': ["X1", "SG", "DV", "XP"]}
    
    dec = {'Month': ["December", "December", "December", "December"],
           'Date': ['1st', '2nd', '28th', '29th'],
           'a': ["d1a", "o3x", "j9c", "h9c"],
           'b': ["X2", "SG", "DV", "XP"]}
    
    a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jan)
    b = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dec)
    
    dfs = [a, b]
    df = pd.concat(dfs)
    
    DateNum = []
    for values in df['Date']:
        DateNum.append(re.search(r'\d+', values).group())
    df['Date Num'] = DateNum
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    dfl = df.Month.tolist()
    months = []
    for data in dfl:
        if data not in months:
            months.append(data)
    # months = ['January', 'December']
    models = []
    for month in months:
        models.append(Model(month))
    
    
    calendar = {}
    for month in models:
        datacopy = df.copy()
        datacopy = datacopy[datacopy.Month == month.name]
        month.data = datacopy
    
        month.update(debug=True)
        calendar[month.name] = month.days
    
    print(json.dumps(calendar, indent=4))
```

Here is the other file - help.py contains the classes Model and Day

```py
    class Model:
        """
        model for months
        """
        name = ""
        data = None
    
        days = {}
    
        def __init__(self, monthname):
            self.name = monthname
    
        def update(self, debug=False):
    
            edit = self.data  # a copy of a slice from the df
            edit = edit.drop("Month", axis=1)  # drop Month column
            edit = edit.set_index('Date Num').T.to_dict('list')  # set Date Num column to be the index and make dict
    
            data_formatted = {self.name: edit}  # save the dict with key as month name as data_formatted
    
            for k, v in data_formatted[self.name].items():  # data_formatted [month] = (day number : data)
    
                if debug:
                    print(k, v)  # e.g. k=1 v=['1st', 'a', 'n']
    
                day_object = Day(v)  # make a day object out of the values (formatting in initializer)
                self.days[k] = day_object.data_formatted  # assign the formatted value e.g. days[1] = (formatted data)
    
                # print(self.days[k])  # shows correct data e.g. {'date': '25th', 'a': 'a', 'b': 'n', 'c': 'x'}
    
    
    class Day:
        date = ""
        a = ""
        b = ""
    
        data_formatted = {}
    
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.date = data[0]
            self.a = data[1]
            self.b = data[2]
    
            self.format_data()
    
        def format_data(self):
            self.data_formatted = {
                "date": self.date,
                "a": self.a,
                "b": self.b,
            }
```

As expected, the data is being processed in the expected order:

```
1 ['1st', 'j1a', 'X1']
2 ['2nd', 'a3x', 'SG']
28 ['28th', 'd9c', 'DV']
29 ['29th', 'h9c', 'XP']
1 ['1st', 'd1a', 'X2']
2 ['2nd', 'o3x', 'SG']
28 ['28th', 'j9c', 'DV']
29 ['29th', 'h9c', 'XP']
```

But the output of the json.dumps is different (identical to the last month in months):

```
{
"January": {
    "1": {
        "date": "1st",
        "a": "d1a", - Should be j1a
        "b": "X2" - should be X1
    },
    "2": {
        "date": "2nd",
        "a": "o3x", - Should be a3x
        "b": "SG"
    } ...
```

Thank you for reading this and I hope you can help me.

Here are some other notes:

- The code without the Model class is being run in an interactive python notebook - could this change things?
- The code I have provided only shows 2 months. In my case, the data from the last month (which I assume to be the last iteration) is being saved as the data for ALL the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    month.data = datacopy

    month.update(debug=True)
    calendar[month.name] = month.days
```

That's fine the first time around, but in the next iteration, you change the data and rerun `.update` for `month`, but its `.days` is still the same dictionary. So, you're not just updating the dictionary for the next month, but also for all previous months.

Edit: you asked for some clarification in the comments - that's fine, it's perhaps not immediately obvious.

The problem starts here, in your `Model` class:

```
class Model:
    ...
    # this is the only place a new dictionary is created
    days = {}  

    def __init__(self, monthname):
        # after __init__, this object will have a reference to the 1 days in your class
        ...

    def update(self, debug=False):
        ...
        for k, v in data_formatted[self.name].items():
            ...
            day_object = Day(v)
            # so here, you just update that one dictionary
            self.days[k] = day_object.data_formatted
```

I've removed the code that doesn't contribute to the problem and added some comments to explain. The key problem is that you defined `days` as an attribute of `Model` - that means it's a class attribute, to which all instances of the class have access, but there's only one of it.

If you need each instance of `Model` to have a unique instance of `.days`, you should just create it in `__init__` (and you don't need it on the class body at all):

```
    def __init__(self, monthname):
        self.name = monthname
        self.days = {}
```

So, the problem is not really to do with loops, the problem is the difference between a class attribute and an object attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems unfortunately I don't completely understand how loops work. From my understanding, the code would be pointing at the next `month` object in the list - How comes it did not do this and instead accessed all the previous objects `.days` dictionaries (Like where you said it is "for all previous months") ?

= How comes `.days` still holds the same dictionary in the next iteration of the loop?

Comment: I've updated the answer - have a look and let me know if it's still not clear. Look up 'class attribute' if you need a bit more information than I included here.

Comment: Thank you so much !

It is now clear to me what I was doing incorrectly - I need to learn more about classes it seems.

Specifically, I did not know that it was a class attribute, rather than an instance attribute - I assumed it was an instance/object attribute by default.